# I want to update Ebay product price using Ebay API

Tags: api, ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-net-sdk

I am searching and trying to update the eBay store price using the eBay API. I have the  App ID DevID and cart ID. I have been trying to update the price using the API. I went through the documentation of eBay API. But couldn't find any proper solution.

Is there any script in PHP that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way ito update price and quantity s to use ReviseInventoryStatus API.
Just need to supply ItemID and price

Then to build procedure you can browse SO:

[How to change product quantity with Ebay API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216053/how-to-change-product-quantity-with-ebay-api)

If you only need to update price/quantity Isuggest you not to use any SDK.